# Executing Geojson2h3 on the browser without Nodejs

Tags: javascript, geojson, h3

I am trying to execute Geojson2h3 on the client browser without Nodejs. I have imported the 'geojson2h3.js' javascript file.
However, I am getting an error with the following code.
I am hoping that this is possible to execute geojson2h3 in the browser.

```
<script src="assets/js/geojson2h3.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/h3binning.js"></script>      
<script src="https://unpkg.com/h3-js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/h3-js@3.7.2/dist/h3-js.umd.js"></script>

function h3binning(){     
    var filename = "sample.geojson"
    var geoJSON = { "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
        "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
        }
      ]
    }

    console.log('geoJSON: geoJSON' )
    console.log('JSON.stringify(geoJSON): ' + JSON.stringify(geoJSON) )
        
    const hexagons2 = geojson2h3.featureToH3Set(geoJSON, 10); //binning level.  
}
```

I receive this error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: geojson2h3 is not defined
    at h3binning (h3binning.js:61:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):467:22)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:43064)
    at v.handle (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:41048)
```